# Google Font API with locally hosted fallback

Tags: font-face, google-font-api

I am using the `Google Font API` to load a font (**CSS**, not font loader) for a project that I'm working on. However, we cannot guarantee that the user who uses the website & device will always have internet connectivity.

We are using **fallbacks** for the loading of jQuery from a CDN but would like to implement a fallback for the font too. It is preferred that the font is loaded from the Google Font API if it is available to reduce load on the device that the website is running from, but if there is no internet connectivity we would like to fallback to the local copy. We have the local copy with stylesheets etc from FontSquirrel so integrating it is no problem.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to check if the font has loaded successfully from the Google Font API and if not to include the local CSS for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google fonts + webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708257/google-fonts-webpack)