# CSS Google Fonts does not show up in App when no internet connection

Tags: google-font-api

I am using [this google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rozha+One?selection.family=Rozha%20One) font in my android app

It all works fine, but when you don't have a internet connection the font does not load, because it needs internet connection to connect to google. How can I avoid this? The start page of my app is using google fonts, and when there is no internet, the start page is just blank, which is very bad.

> How can I use this font offline?

Comment: I've added an answer for this on a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708257/google-fonts-webpack/48310258#48310258

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google fonts + webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708257/google-fonts-webpack)