# webpack recursive loader for css\scss url imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

in order to serve all of my resources from the same server, i would like to bundle the fonts that the application is using by either:

1. include the fonts within the generated bundle file (e.g. `app.js`), or by
2. downloading the fonts and modify the generated bundle file to refer to the fonts locally relatively

i tried to do so by [`file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) and [`url-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) for [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), but when i open the generated html file (e.g. `index.html`) in the browser, requests for [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) are shown in the [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) (yes, google fonts are used and credits will be given, but would like to have the fonts served from the server which runs the app), and i would not like to see such requests.

for instance, assume that my `*.scss` files include the `@import url('...')` statement, is there any plugin\loader for webpack that will recursively download all the resources and will bundle them (like mentioned above)?

p.s.
although i came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310258)

> Both loaders will pack url() statements. However, they both will only work if the URL is a relative URL

i am still interested in more up to date answer.