# How to preload Google Fonts from CDN with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preload

My goal is to import the fonts by:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:i,100,200,300);
```

in my `.scss` file, then preload all the fonts by [preload-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin)

---

After I deployed my bundle, the google fonts are applied, and the font request is like this:

[image]

Compare to the request which utilized `@font-face` in the `.scss` file, get the fonts downloaded to local then served by myself:

[image]

Only the file name of second one follows the `name` I defined in `file-loader` configuration:

```js
exports.font = {
  test:   /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  query:  {
    name: '[name]-[hash:6].[ext]',
  },
};
```

It's still reasonable for me, so my guess is, I think when Webpack is creating Dependency Graph `css-loader` interprets `@import` and `url()`, then `file-loader` duplicates the files to our dist folder, but if the source is from external, `file-loader` won't work on that.

---

Again, compare requests to CDN and local, the **Sources** section in Devtool shows me:

- CDN:

[image]

- Local:

[image]

When I request fonts from CDN there is a new folder **gstatic**, before I add [preload-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin), the fonts are requested dynamically when meet the new fonts family/style in the new pages, after I add [preload-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin), the fonts are preloaded only for the way which is sending fonts request to local.

```js
exports.preloadWebpack = new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
  rel:           'preload',
  include:       'allAssets',
  fileWhitelist: [/\.woff/, /\.woff2/, /\.ttf/],
  as:            'font',
});
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using: Google Fonts Webpack Plugin,

and install it using npm in this way:

`npm install @beyonk/google-fonts-webpack-plugin`

More [info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@beyonk/google-fonts-webpack-plugin).

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried this before, but seems set `local` to true or false in this plugin just equals to the two ways I did in my question. So, I am just not sure if there is any opportunity that webpack could download/request all external sources in all `.scss` files right immediately after we visit the page (after the request to our entry somewhere like index.html).